# jQuery Remove img tag by ID name not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read through other posts, but I am still not sure why my code isn't working. I am looking for an element with an id of featured-### to remove.

```
$('.model-gallery-image').click(function(){
    featured_remove($(this).attr('data-model-id'));
});

function featured_remove(model_num){
    console.log('Remove Featured Image: #featured-' + model_num);

    $('#featured-' + model_num).remove();
}
```

I have logged the model_num to the console to verify that the number is being passed.

Here is what the html tag looks like when I inspect it through the browser.

```
<img src="model-gallery/37eafefa4964d985cb6f2e3bda07458c9b0728f5.jpg" id="featured-6">
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: should work fine..., I guess model_num has something wrong..., show the code for model_num

Comment: Are you trying to remove it before it loaded in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your script is called before the element actually exists, you should check and otherwise i dont know what could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

In your function `featured_remove()` is undefined because it's out of the context.

Pass a parameter to use the outer function:

```
//define your function
var featured_remove = function (model_num){
    console.log('Remove Featured Image: #featured-' + model_num);

    $('#featured-' + model_num).remove();
}
//using closure
$('.model-gallery-image').click(function(featured_remove){//pass variable here
    featured_remove($(this).attr('data-model-id'));
});
```